# Changing odometer colour

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

Hi I have an odometer from http://dashboarding.codeplex.com/

I would like to change the colour of the odometer, but am unable to do so. I have tried changing the background property of the odometer, or using styles for the odometer but it doesn't work.

Anyone has any idea how to do so?

Comment: Ask it to http://dashboarding.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: Tried asking but to no avail.

Comment: You asked it on sunday :) People have a life :) wait.

Comment: Alright I understand, however there was another similar question that was posted there last year. Hence I thought there was no point asking there and asked here instead. Sorry if I seemed impatient..